# On jQuery .change find which instance of .class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm running a function when an input with a given class is changed. I want to be able to find which instance of that class was changed(0,1, or 2). How can this be done?

```
<input class="class"/>
<input class="class"/>
<input class="class"/>
<div class="object"></div>
<div class="object"></div>
<div class="object"></div>

<script>
$('.class').change(function() {
  // Need to get variable i to equal the instance of .class (0,1, or 2)
  $('.object:eq(i)').css('fill', $(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

`$(this).index()` inside the change event will give you the index of the element relative to its sibling elements.

But if you the container of the inputs has other elements appearing before the inputs then a better bet would be.

```
$('.class').index(this); //Or $('.class', 'containerSelector').index(this)
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nY6Wn/)

Comment: The general concept is that `this`, when referenced inside your event handler, will refer to the actual element that was changed. As described in this answer, you can then use `index()` to get the value that you need for the rest of your handler to work.